# Find OffSetAccount using SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a raw data in a table as below:-

[image]

i need a SQL query that show same data in below format.

[image]

mean i need OffsetAccount of each entry on document level.

my working is shown below:-

```
Create Table Abc (Head Nvarchar(100),[Date] Date,Document nvarchar(500),Dr decimal(20,2),Cr decimal(20,2))

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('ADVANCES TO VENDORS FROM OUTLETS' , '2019-02-27' , ' SVM-MRD1214' , 95253 , 0 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('COMMISSION EXPENSES' , '2019-02-27' , ' SVM-MRD1214' , 3148 , 0 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('GENERATOR FUEL AND MAINTAINANCE' , '2019-02-27' , ' SVM-MRD1214' , 1450 , 0 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('GROSS SALES' , '2019-02-27' , ' SVM-MRD1214' , 0 , -99951 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('PRINTING & STATIONARY EXPENSES' , '2019-02-27' , ' SVM-MRD1214' , 20 , 0 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('TRAVELLING & CONVEYANCE EXPENSES' , '2019-02-27' , ' SVM-MRD1214' , 80 , 0 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('ADVANCES TO MALIK TANVEER' , '2019-02-27' , ' SVM-SLK21588' , 5410 , 0 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('GENERATOR FUEL AND MAINTAINANCE' , '2019-02-27' , ' SVM-SLK21588' , 6410 , 0 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('GROSS SALES' , '2019-02-27' , ' SVM-SLK21588' , 0 , -16870 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('INVENTORY REPAIR & CLAIMS' , '2019-02-27' , ' SVM-SLK21588' , 1000 , 0 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('POSTAGE AND CARRIAGE' , '2019-02-27' , ' SVM-SLK21588' , 200 , 0 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('TRAVELLING & CONVEYANCE EXPENSES' , '2019-02-27' , ' SVM-SLK21588' , 1230 , 0 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('WATER EXPENSES' , '2019-02-27' , ' SVM-SLK21588' , 2620 , 0 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('ADVANCES TO MALIK TANVEER' , '2019-02-09' , ' SVM-SWT0572' , 53679 , 0 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('COMMISSION EXPENSES' , '2019-02-09' , ' SVM-SWT0572' , 463 , 0 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('GROSS SALES' , '2019-02-09' , ' SVM-SWT0572' , 53679 , 0 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Abc] ([Head] ,[Date] ,[Document]  ,[Dr],[Cr]) Values ('GROSS SALES' , '2019-02-09' , ' SVM-SWT0572' , 0 , -107821 )
```

we will discuss Document # SVM-SWT0572 for understanding. in this document account "ADVANCES TO MALIK TANVEER" debited by amount 53679.00 and COMMISSION EXPENSES debited by amount 463.00 and GROSS SALES debited by 53679.00 all above accounts are debiting by account GROSS SALES having amount -107821.00 ,So Gross Sales account is Offsetaccount of all above (ADVANCES TO MALIK TANVEER, COMMISSION EXPENSES , GROSS SALES) accounts.

Comment: You've said what you need here, but what is your question? What have you tried so far to get the results you are after? Where did you get stuck or what errors did you get?

Comment: What is the logic for generating the `OffSetAccount` column?

Comment: What does that comment even mean? I appreciate there's a language barrier here, but we don't need to discuss the definition of your data. We need you to tell us what your question is (as you haven't asked one) and explain the problems your having. If you're trying to get a dataset from another, then explain the logic behind it as well. Thanks.

Comment: we will discuss Document #  SVM-SWT0572 for understanding. in this document  account "ADVANCES TO MALIK TANVEER" is debiting by amount 53679.00 and COMMISSION EXPENSES is debiting by amount 463.00 and GROSS SALES is debiting by 53679.00 all above accounts are debiting by  account GROSS SALES having amount -107821.00 so, Gross Sales account is Offsetaccount of all above (ADVANCES TO MALIK TANVEER, COMMISSION EXPENSES  ,  GROSS SALES) accounts.

Comment: Please add all clarifying information by editing your question, not by adding them to the comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
declare @abc table
(
  Head Nvarchar(100),
  [Date] Date,
  Document nvarchar(500),
  Dr decimal(20,2),
  Cr decimal(20,2)
)

insert into @abc (Head, [Date], Document, Dr, Cr)
values
('ADVANCES TO VENDORS FROM OUTLETS', '2019-02-27', ' SVM-MRD1214', 95253, 0),
('COMMISSION EXPENSES', '2019-02-27', ' SVM-MRD1214', 3148, 0),
('GENERATOR FUEL AND MAINTENANCE', '2019-02-27', ' SVM-MRD1214', 1450, 0),
('GROSS SALES', '2019-02-27', ' SVM-MRD1214', 0, -99951),
('PRINTING & STATIONARY EXPENSES', '2019-02-27', ' SVM-MRD1214', 20, 0),
('TRAVELLING & CONVEYANCE EXPENSES', '2019-02-27', ' SVM-MRD1214', 80, 0),
('ADVANCES TO MALIK TANVEER', '2019-02-27', ' SVM-SLK21588', 5410, 0),
('GENERATOR FUEL AND MAINTENANCE', '2019-02-27', ' SVM-SLK21588', 6410, 0),
('GROSS SALES', '2019-02-27', ' SVM-SLK21588', 0, -16870),
('INVENTORY REPAIR & CLAIMS', '2019-02-27', ' SVM-SLK21588', 1000, 0),
('POSTAGE AND CARRIAGE', '2019-02-27', ' SVM-SLK21588', 200, 0),
('TRAVELLING & CONVEYANCE EXPENSES', '2019-02-27', ' SVM-SLK21588', 1230, 0),
('WATER EXPENSES', '2019-02-27', ' SVM-SLK21588', 2620, 0),
('ADVANCES TO MALIK TANVEER', '2019-02-09', ' SVM-SWT0572', 53679, 0),
('COMMISSION EXPENSES', '2019-02-09', ' SVM-SWT0572', 463, 0),
('GROSS SALES', '2019-02-09', ' SVM-SWT0572', 53679, 0),
('GROSS SALES', '2019-02-09', ' SVM-SWT0572', 0, -107821);

--insert into @abc (Head, [Date], Document, Dr, Cr) values ('GROSS SALES', '2019-02-27', ' SVM-MRD1214', 0, -99951);  --for testing validation

--select * from @abc;

--verify that there is only one credit row per Date + Document combination because remaining code is dependent on that condition being true to generate an accurate result set
if (exists (select [Date], Document, rows = count(1) from @abc where Dr = 0 and Cr <> 0 group by [Date], Document having count(1) > 1))
begin
  raiserror('invalid input data', 1, 1);
  return; --abort script
end;

--generate result set
with
list as
(
  select
  dr.Head,
  dr.[Date],
  dr.Document,
  dr.Dr,
  dr.Cr,
  OffSetAccount = cr.Head
  from @abc dr
  inner join @abc cr
  on dr.[Date] = cr.[Date]
  and dr.Document = cr.Document
  where dr.Dr <> 0 and dr.Cr = 0  --debits
  and cr.Dr = 0 and cr.Cr <> 0 --credits
)
select
Head,
[Date],
Document,
Dr,
Cr,
OffSetAccount
from list
union all
select
Head = OffSetAccount,
[Date],
Document,
Dr = Cr,
Cr = -Dr,
OffSetAccount = Head
from list
order by
[Date],
Document,
Dr desc,
Cr asc;
```

Result set:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Knot22 ,     what will be code if credit side have multiple row instead of single row. I have found some document having multiple rows in credit side.

Comment: The answer provided only permits single rows on the credit side as that is what the original question asked.  Please post a new/separate question with an example of multiple rows on the credit side, the desired result set and a description of the logic behind the results set.